# Moving CSS rules from a CSS file to inline attributes

Tags: code-golf

The goal is to take CSS rules from a regular CSS file and apply them to their respective targets in an HTML file, but by placing the rules in the `style=""` attribute (using the [`<style>` tag](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_style.asp) would be too simple) and removing the `class=""` and `id=""` attributes.

Rules:

- Only ids `#id` and classes `.class` selectors must be supported, without more complex rules (parent selector `#a #b` or multiple classes `.a.b`, etc.)
- Reducing rules is not required, for example the rules `#a{color:red} .b{color:blue}` applied to `<div id="a" class="b"></div>` can output `<div style="color:blue;color:red;"></div>` and the browser will only use the last rule (hereby red)
- The paths to input files can be transmitted by command line arguments or hard-coded in the script/program
- You can't call an external library, you can only include classes or functions built in the language (or from another language if needed)
- [Standard “loopholes”](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/standard-loopholes-which-are-no-longer-funny) are forbidden
- You program must produce the expected result but also works with other input files (to avoid hard-coded solution)
- The output does not need to be saved to any file
- Shortest code wins

### Inputs:

#### CSS file

```css
#h1 {color:Red;}
#bigger {font-size:1.1em;}
.code {font-family:Monospace;}
.golf {background-color:LightGreen;}
```

Only ids and classes are used in order to keep it simple.

#### HTML file

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><title>Hello World!</title></head>
<body>
<h1 id="h1">Hello World!</h1>
<ol>
    <li class="code">Code</li>
    <li id="bigger" class="golf">Golf</li>
    <li class="code golf">Code golf</li>
</ol>
</body>
</html>
```

### Expected output:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><title>Hello World!</title></head>
<body>
<h1 style="color:Red">Hello World!</h1>
<ol>
    <li style="font-family:Monospace;">Code</li>
    <li style="font-size:1.1em;background-color:LightGreen;">Golf</li>
    <li style="font-family:Monospace;background-color:LightGreen;">Code golf</li>
</ol>
</body>
</html>
```

[Example on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BpaYe/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### bash + sed <s>133</s> <s>185</s> 179

```
sed -re 's/ass="([^"]*) ([^"]*)"/ass="\1" class="\2"/g;'"$(
    sed -re 's/^#/id§/;s/^\./class§/;
        s/(.*)§(\S*) \{(.*)\}/s@\1="\2"@style="\3"@g/' $CSS
      )"';s/yle="(.*)" style="/yle="\1/g' $HTML
```

```
sed -re 's/class="([^"]*) ([^"]*)"/class="\1" class="\2"/g;
    '"$(sed -re 's/^#/id /;s/^\./class /;
        s/(\S*) (\S*) \{(.*)\}/s@\1="\2"@style="\3"@g/' $CSS
    )"';s/style="(.*)" style="/style="\1/g' $HTML
```

In this (specific) case, this will render:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><title>Hello World!</title></head>
<body>
<h1 style="color:Red;">Hello World!</h1>
<ol>
    <li style="font-family:Monospace;">Code</li>
    <li style="font-size:1.1em;background-color:LightGreen;">Golf</li>
    <li style="font-family:Monospace;background-color:LightGreen;">Code golf</li>
</ol>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The classes are ignored?

Comment: Oops, multi-class support add 52 bytes...

Answer (score 3):

## Python - <del>508</del>, <del>501</del>, 483

The idea is to read all the rules then apply them by using xpath functions, too bad it can't select nodes with multiple classes (I didn't find own to target `class="code golf"`).

### Golfed

```py
import sys,xml.etree.ElementTree as E
r=E.parse(sys.argv[2])
def a(e,f):e.set('style',(e.attrib.get('style')or'')+f)
for l in open(sys.argv[1]):
 s=l.replace("\n",'').split(' ');b=s[0];c=s[1][1:-1]
 if(b[:1])=='#':
  for e in r.findall('.//*[@id=\''+b[1:]+'\']'):a(e,c);e.attrib.pop('id')
 else:
  for e in r.findall('.//*[@class]'):
   d=e.attrib.get('class').split(' ')
   if b[1:]in d:
    a(e,c);e.set('class',' '.join(d[1:]))
    if len(d) == 1: e.attrib.pop('class')
E.dump(r)
```

### Usage

`python script.py input.css input.html`

### Ungolfed code

```py
import sys, xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
root = ET.parse(sys.argv[2])

# append rules to style="" attribute
def a(e,f):
    e.set('style',(e.attrib.get('style')or'') + f)

# CSS file
for l in open(sys.argv[1]):
    split = l.replace("\n", '').split(' ')
    selector = split[0]
    rules = split[1][1:-1]

    # #id
    if (b[0:1]) == '#':
        for e in root.findall('.//*[@id=\''+selector[1:]+'\']'):
            a(e,rules)
            # remove id
            e.attrib.pop('id')
    # .class
    else:
        for e in root.findall('.//*[@class]'):
            d=e.attrib.get('class').split(' ')
            if selector[1:] in d:
                a(e,rules)
                e.set('class', ' '.join(d[1:]))
                # remove class
                if len(d) == 1:
                    e.attrib.pop('class')

ET.dump(root)
```

Comment: You can get it down to 475 by indenting with only one space and also in your first `for` loop use `;` to remove line breaks and also the indenting, you also had a space in `a(e,c);e.set('class',' '.join(d[1:]))`.

Comment: You can also replace `b[0:1]` with `b[:1]`

Comment: @BritishColour : thanks, I will update my answer in the next days.

Comment: @BritishColour : I replaced the tabs with spaces, but I'm not sure it saves space to use one space or one tab since both are characters. How should I use `;` to remove line breaks? Thanks.

Comment: In the first `for` loop instead of having each line with a \n and four spaces change it so that it is `line1;line2;line3` ect

Comment: @BritishColour : I thought you suggested to change the `for` loop to something else. I see now.

Comment: Yep, that's what I meant :)

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript - 589 (573)

It's 573 when processed by a minifier.

Not smaller then the Python version, but processes CSS using DOM objects instead of text strings. This should be able to process more complex CSS selectors also. But then the `id` and `class` attributes are not handled at the moment.

```
x=document
x.write('<link rel="stylesheet" href="'+c+'"/>')
window.onload=function(){
var s,p,n,t,i,j,r=x.styleSheets[0].cssRules,d=x.getElementById('i').contentWindow.document
for(i=0;i<r.length;i++){s=r[i].selectorText
p=r[i].cssText.match(/\{\s*(.*?)\s*\}/)
n=d.querySelectorAll(s)
for(j=0;j<n.length;j++){t=n[j].getAttribute('style')==null?'':n[j].getAttribute('style')
n[j].setAttribute('style',(t+p[1]).replace(': ',':'))
n[j].removeAttribute(s.charAt(0)=='#'?'id':'class')
}}alert(new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(d))}
x.write('<iframe src="'+h+'" id="i"></iframe>')
```

Runs in Firefox if you put the script, the files to process and this web page in the same folder:

```
<html><body>
<script type="text/javascript">
var c='css2inline.css',
    h='css2inline-input.html'
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="a.js"></script>
</body></html>
```

Replace `c` and `h` with CSS and HTML files, open this page and an alert shows the HTML.

**Note** The resulting HTML is a serialization of the DOM tree. That causes the result to be not exactly formatted as requested, but it represents the same HTML. Your call to say if you find it correct or not.

Expanded:

```
// Add CSS to current document.
x = document
x.write('<link rel="stylesheet" href="'+c+'"/>')

window.onload = function(){
    var s,p,n,t,i,j,
        r = x.styleSheets[0].cssRules,

        // Get the HTML to process.
        d = x.getElementById('i').contentWindow.document

    // Loop through CSS rules.    
    for(i = 0; i < r.length; i++){

        // Get CSS selector from rule.
        s = r[i].selectorText

        // Get text with CSS properties.
        p = r[i].cssText.match(/\{\s*(.*?)\s*\}/)

        // Get DOM nodes matching the CSS selector.
        n = d.querySelectorAll(s)

        // Add CSS properties to style of selected nodes.
        for(j = 0; j < n.length; j++){

            // Preserve current value.
            t = n[j].getAttribute('style') == null ? '' : n[j].getAttribute('style')

            // Add rule properties.         
            n[j].setAttribute('style',(t + p[1]).replace(': ',':'))

            // Remove id/class attribute from element.
            n[j].removeAttribute(s.charAt(0) == '#' ? 'id' : 'class')
        }
    }
    // Output serialized document.
    alert(new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(d))
}

// Create document with input HTML.
x.write('<iframe src="'+h+'" id="i"></iframe>')
```

Comment: I started thinking about a jQuery solution yesterday but I didn't find an easy way to modify the HTML page inplace. I like the idea of the `</iframe>`. I don't see any problem with the serialization if it's only differences in tabulation.

Comment: With jQuery it might be possible to reduce code size. But that can't work without the jQuery library. And I liked investigating the DOM manipulation for CSS.

Comment: Oops, in fact the rules don't allow jQuery because it's not a part of the Javascript language. I started to think about a pure JS solution.

Comment: Buggy. If a node has an id and a class, it should get the rules of both, where they don't conflict. Where they do conflict, `#id` should have priority over `.class` regardless of the order of the rules in the CSS.

Comment: @Peter_Taylor: true, the script doesn't do that. But that's not how I read the requirements. And from my limited Python knowledge I don't see it handled in the Python version either. But I may very well be wrong about that.

Comment: this can definitely be trimmed down more manually. Drop the `var`, assign `n[j].getAttribute('style')`, change `charAt(0)` to `[0]`, no need for `.replace(': ',':')`... but does it work with two classes?  Also, this seems to only work with XHTML, not HTML5 (I don't think it will output tags that are not XML-compliant).

Answer (score 1):

## Lua - <s>340</s> 335

```
f='(%w+)'a={}b={}for l in io.lines(arg[2])do i=l:sub(1,1)t=i=='#'and a or b
k,v=l:match(f..' {(.-)}')t[k]=v end
for l in io.lines(arg[1])do
c=''g='class="(.-)"'h='style="'l=l:gsub('id='..f,function(v)l:gsub(g,function(e)c=e:gsub(f,b)end)return h..a[v]..c..'"'end)l=l:gsub(g,function(e)return #c<1 and h..e:gsub(f,b)..'"'end)print(l)end
```

**Usage:** execute from the command line `lua script.lua input.html input.css`